# jquery trigger function when an element is hidden

Tags: jquery, events

What would be the best way to trigger a function when a certain DIV is hidden.

I want to destroy some Flash object from the page when an element is hidden, and re-create them when the element is shown.

e.g.

```
<div id="flashContainer> // flash object </div>

$("#flashContainer).hide(); //trigger function that destroys the flash object
$("#flashContainer).show(); //trigger function that creates the flash object
```

Background:

The reason I want to do this, is that I have a long page, with some navigation that "steps throught" divs as if they were pages. In IE, all these hidden divs load up the flash and start downloading the video, hogging memory and bandwidth in the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [provides an override](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to the show() and hide() methods that allows you to pass a callback function that is fired once the animation is complete

> .show( duration, [ callback ] )

You could use this like

```
$('#flashContainer').hide('slow', function(e) {
  //put your code here to remove your flash
  $('#flashId').remove();  //something like this maybe
  alert('hidden');
});

$('#flashContainer').show('slow', function(e) {
  //add your flash here
});
```

However in the case of `show()`, the `flashcontainer` will be shown before your flash object is loaded so you may want to create your flash before calling `show()` something like

```
$('#flashcontainer').append('<object><!-- your flash html here --></object>');
$('#flashcontainer').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#flashContainer:hidden").show();
```

Taken from jQuery offical page, does this help?

Can you be more specific?

Comment: this would just display the containers I already have hidden, I need to trigger an event when DIVs of a certain type (defined by class) are shown/hidden

Comment: then what you need is an IF statement, and/or a setInterval function to keep checking whether DIV's are :hidden

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to show and hide the flash object rather than crating and destroying.

Something like

```
$("#flashContainer).hide("slow", function(){
    $("#yourflashobjid").hide();
});

$("#flashContainer).show("slow", function(){
    $("#yourflashobjid").show();
});
```

Comment: why would if be better to hide/show the object, I do that anyway when I hide/show the containing div. In everything BUT IE, the object gets destroyed *anyway* becuase of a bug in the Gecko rendering https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268. I just need to make sure it gets destroyed in IE